# Establish Itext table width using SetWidthPercentage method in VB net

Tags: vb.net, itext

I have a table which I need to fill 100% of the whole page. This is the code I used:

```
....
       Dim tamanyo_tabla As New Rectangle(PageSize.A4)
            Dim dimensiones_tabla(11) As Single
            dimensiones_tabla(0) = 3
            dimensiones_tabla(1) = 3
            dimensiones_tabla(2) = 10
            dimensiones_tabla(3) = 10
            dimensiones_tabla(4) = 10
            dimensiones_tabla(5) = 8.33
            dimensiones_tabla(6) = 8.33
            dimensiones_tabla(7) = 12.5
            dimensiones_tabla(8) = 8.33
            dimensiones_tabla(9) = 8.33
            dimensiones_tabla(10) = 6
            dimensiones_tabla(11) = 12.18
            table_sem.SetWidthPercentage(dimensiones_tabla, tamanyo_tabla)
....
```

If you sum all the figures from the array `dimensiones_tabla` you will notice its 100%.

I based this on this example(it has no updates, eventhough the method has changed): http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=79

I open the pdf and I found the table width is far from being 100% of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width percentage like this:

```
table_sem.SetWidthPercentage(dimensiones_tabla, tamanyo_tabla)
```

The total of all the widths in `dimensiones_tabla` is 100 user units (1.3889 inch). The width of `tamanyo_tabla` is 595 user units. Hence you are defining a width percentage of 100 / 595 = 16.8%. 16.8% is indeed far from being 100% of the page.

If you want the table to take 100% of the available width of the page, why don't you just set the width percentage to 100%?

```
table_sem.setWidthPercentage(100); // Java!
```

In VB, this would probably look like this:

```
table_sem.WidthPercentage = 100 // VB
```

Note that this will not be 100% of the *total* page, because you probably have a left and a right margin that is greater than 0. If you want the table to cover the complete page width, you need to set the left and right margin to 0.